# ios magnetometer: force display of calibration view

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, calibration, magnetometer

As an user of a mechanical compass, I noticed that the heading that the magnetometer delivers, is often off by 45 degrees or more, although the calibration display did not appear in that cases.

If I test, or use my app outdoors, I ever calibrate the magnetometer when my compass view comes up. This works, it seems that this is necessary.

I don't want to show the users of my app an inaccurate heading, when it is possible to achieve an more or less accurate one, by performig a frequent calibration with the figure eight motion.

Does anybody know a solution to force the display of the magnetometer calibration view, every time my compass view comes up?

I searched all(?) posts here, only one person had a similar idea, but without an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way to do this - whilst the API allows you to *dismiss* the calibration view (using the `dismissHeadingCalibrationDisplay` call) to prevent it from interrupting your app's interface, there's no way to force a calibration to start. I'd suggest filing a feature request with Apple if you think it's something that might be useful.

Comment: There's no API, but [this simple method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42877044/1971013) works.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any api for that in ios6 and below :(

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager
*)manager {
        if(!manager.heading) return YES; // Got nothing, We can assume we got to calibrate.
        else if( manager.heading.headingAccuracy < 0 ) return YES; // 0 means invalid heading, need to calibrate
        else if( manager.heading.headingAccuracy > 5 )return YES; // 5 degrees is a small value correct for my needs, too.
        else return NO; // All is good. Compass is precise enough.
    }
```

**Font:** [Compass calibration objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089155/compass-calibration-objective-c)

Comment: The question was different: Asume ios thinks the calibration is currently not needed, but I think it is always needed, so i want the calibratuion view, whenever I show my compass.

Comment: `locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:` is called _the first time heading updates are ever requested_, so you can `startHeadingUpdates` as soon as you show the compass and return TRUE. Was that what you tried to do?

Comment: no, when hiking outdoors you need the compass often. but the compass is only acurate if you always calibrate it immeadetly befire using it. so i want to force!! the calibration view to be shown whenever my app decides to show it.

Comment: you code will not run. you're comparing `CLHeading` against accuracyDegree. Also the method gets called after the first heading update.

Answer (score 1):

**Grab a fridge magnet** and move it at around top of your iPhone's screen.  You may also need to rotate your iPhone on a few axis at the same time; be creative.

Be aware that to fool the magnetometer again with a magnet, you may need to allow it to reset itself to the Earth magnetic field.  You do this by rotating the iPhone over all axis.

I had a bug which occurred after the calibration screen disappeared again.  The above method allowed me to force it to appear at will within 10 seconds or so.

Some additional information: When the calibration screen appears AppDelegate's `applicationWillResignActive` is called. Then when it's done: `applicationDidBecomeActive`. (My bug: I only restarted my motion manager in `applicationWillEnterForeground`, not in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.)