# Compass calibration objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dictionary

I try use compass in my ios app. And I have one problem with it. If i implement 
`locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration` method and `return YES` in it, then calibration display is showing always. But I should make it like apple maps. I.e. calibration display should be showed sometimes. When compass should be calibration.

Comment: I dont think that this is true, I like to force that calibration is always shown, but it will only be shown if device thinks it is needed. Which ios?

Comment: v6+, and I use OSM maps

Comment: My experience is if you are outdoors and having a mechanical compass, then I see that ypou have to calibrate the iphone each time you use it. So I want to force the calibration view to come up, even when ios thinks its is not neccessary. But this does not work, you cannot force it to show the calib window. try it out: calibrate it, then leave view, enter again, do you see the calibration view again?

Comment: I have the opposite problem: the calibration dialog (implemented exactly as yours) is never shown, even if in the exact same location (i.e. seated at my desk) the 'Compass' application continuously shows the dialog.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK I could not leave a comment so I thought I should leave a reply as Claude Houle's reply was useful to me.

I am using this improved version of Claude Houle's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917110/2332101).

```
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager{
      if(!manager.heading) return YES; // Got nothing, We can assume we got to calibrate.
      else if(manager.heading.headingAccuracy < 0 ) return YES; // 0 means invalid heading, need to calibrate
      else if(manager.heading.headingAccuracy > 5 ) return YES; // 5 degrees is a small value correct for my needs, too.
      else return NO; // All is good. Compass is precise enough.
}
```

Also wanted to say what Claude Houle says almost implements the API docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:) which states:

> If you return NO from this method or **do not provide an implementation for it** in your delegate, Core Location does not display the heading calibration alert. Even if the alert is not displayed, calibration can still occur naturally when any interfering magnetic fields move away from the device. **However, if the device is unable to calibrate itself for any reason, the value in the headingAccuracy property of any subsequent events will reflect the uncalibrated readings.**

Comment: Thanks for that. Just checked my code and yes there was that error, updated the answer. Your response is more concise (knowing null is 0). For a beginner like me at the time, may help explain those few checks.

Comment: Have you ever seen `headingAccuracy` to be lower than 5 when `locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration` was called? I guess your answer is no because 5 degrees would be too close to the accuracy iOS can guarantee (on some devices at least). I think [Wim Verhoef](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29999343/1971013) has a valid point.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLHeading * currentHeading; // Value updated by @selector(locationManager:didUpdateHeading:)
...
...
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager{
      if( !self.currentHeading ) return YES; // Got nothing, We can assume we got to calibrate.
      else if( self.currentHeading.headingAccuracy < 0 ) return YES; // 0 means invalid heading. we probably need to calibrate
      else if( self.currentHeading.headingAccuracy > 5 )return YES; // 5 degrees is a small value correct for my needs. Tweak yours according to your needs.
      else return NO; // All is good. Compass is precise enough.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A much more straight-forward solution:

**Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager
{
    CLLocationDirection accuracy = [[manager heading] headingAccuracy];
    return accuracy <= 0.0f || accuracy > 10.0f;
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that selectors performed on nil objects always return zero, and the fact the the accuracy is never going to be valid and equal to 0.0f (i.e. 100% accurate).

**Swift**

Due to the introduction of optionals, the simplest Swift solution does require branching and would look something like:

```
func locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration(manager: CLLocationManager) -> Bool {
    if let h = manager.heading {
        return h.headingAccuracy < 0 || h.headingAccuracy > 10
    }
    return true
}
```

Note that we're looking at `headingAccuracy`, for which Apple's docs state:

> A positive value in this property represents the potential error
>   between the value reported by the magneticHeading property and the
>   actual direction of magnetic north. Thus, the lower the value of this
>   property, the more accurate the heading. A negative value means that
>   the reported heading is invalid, which can occur when the device is
>   uncalibrated or there is strong interference from local magnetic
>   fields.

Answer (score 2):

manager.heading  is   CLHeading. that is why   manager.heading > 5   will give a warning.   self.currentHeading.headingAccuracy > 5     is the true one.

Answer (score 0):

On my iPhone6 the headingAccuracy is typically 25.0 so just returning YES and relying on iOS to determine when to show the calibration screen seems the best thing to do.
Discarding readings with headingAccuracy < 0.0 prevents the use of 'wrong' headings.

Comment: @JProgrammer I believe it is an answer and a valid one too.