# Turn off compass calibration in iOS app

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, locationmanager, calibration

My app requests the user's location (which I don't think I need), but it almost ALWAYS asks the user to calibrate (which is very annoying).

I have seen this on here: locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration
which states setting this to Yes will request the user to calibrate, but I don't have this anywhere in my code so I cannot understand WHY it is happening!

Ideally, I'd like to solve this ASAP so I can submit. Its the only thing currently holding me back.

Comment: Implement that delegate method and return `NO`.

Comment: @rmaddy `NO` is the default behaviour according to Apple's documentation, and it will still present a calibration alert in some situations even with a `NO` response, although it doesn't look like it should happen very often unless your phone is next to a magnet or something.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. "My app requests the user's location" - but compass calibration has to do with _heading_, not location. Does your app request the user's _heading_? Then if you want true-north heading, you must allow for the possibility of calibration; you cannot prevent it if the system decides the device needs it. Why is this bad? You are the one who wants the heading, and the system can't provide it without the calibration. Don't worry, be happy. Submit the app.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I posted my comment after not seeing what the default was in the docs but after a 2nd look I now see where it says that `NO` is the default if not implemented. Thanks.

Comment: take a look here  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089155/compass-calibration-objective-c